# XSLT: distinct iteration of children starting at specific child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to import a list of users to our database.

The import file is an excel file with these column specifications:

```
Firstname | Lastname | Username | E-Mail | Phone | Group1 | Group2 |...
```

Every user is at least in one usergroup, but can have more than one. The usergroups start at the sixth column.
We use a program that uses specific XML Tags to import the data, so I have to transform the given file to this format.
The first thing I need to do is import every user group to the database. It is important that I only add every group once.

This is the XML file I get after transforming the excel file to XML via a .net DataSet:

```
<ImportFile.xlsx>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Wendy</Column1>
    <Column2>Darling</Column2>
    <Column3>WDarling</Column3>
    <Column4>WDarling@TheDarlings.com</Column4>
    <Column6>Children</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>John</Column1>
    <Column2>Darling</Column2>
    <Column3>JDarling</Column3>
    <Column4>JDarling@TheDarlings.com</Column4>
    <Column6>Children</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Michael</Column1>
    <Column2>Darling</Column2>
    <Column3>MDarling</Column3>
    <Column6>Children</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Mr</Column1>
    <Column2>Darling</Column2>
    <Column3>MrDarling</Column3>
    <Column4>MrDarling@TheDarlings.com</Column4>
    <Column5>555-12345</Column5>
    <Column6>DarlingFamily</Column6>
    <Column7>Parents</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Mrs</Column1>
    <Column2>Darling</Column2>
    <Column3>MrsDarling</Column3>
    <Column4>MrsDarling@TheDarlings.com</Column4>
    <Column5>555-12345</Column5>
    <Column6>Parents</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Nana</Column1>
    <Column2>TheDog</Column2>
    <Column3>Nana</Column3>
    <Column6>Animals</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
  <Tabelle1>
    <Column1>Liza</Column1>
    <Column2>TheMaid</Column2>
    <Column3>Liza</Column3>
    <Column4>Maid</Column4>
    <Column6>Maid</Column6>
    <Column7>DarlingFamily</Column7>
  </Tabelle1>
</ImportFile.xlsx>
```

Notice that some users don't have E-Mail adresses or phone numbers. in these cases entries with tags  or  are missing. Also some users are only in one group, others are in three, so sometimes there is a  tag and sometimes there isn't.

This is my transformation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- New XSLT document created with EditiX XML Editor (http://www.editix.com) at Thu Mar 23 16:00:24 CET 2017 -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="gruppe" match="*/Tabelle1/*[starts-with(name(), 'Column')][position() >= 4]/text()" use="." />

    <xsl:template match="/">
<root>
            <xsl:for-each select="*/Tabelle1/Column6/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('gruppe',.)[1])] | 
                                  */Tabelle1/Column6/following-sibling::*/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('gruppe',.)[1])]">
                    <Name><xsl:value-of select="."/></Name>
            </xsl:for-each>
</root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By using the key "gruppe" at the start and "generate-id()" in the for-each loop I achieve the discinct selection of groups. The for-each loop should be okay, I only iterate at Column6 and it's siblings (i.e Column7, Column8 etc.).

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
<Name>Children</Name>
<Name>DarlingFamily</Name>
<Name>Parents</Name>
<Name>Animals</Name>
</root>
```

The problem now is that the group "Maid" of "Liza The Maid" is missing. 
This is probably because her e-Mail Adress has the same name as her group, and because of that generate-id generates different IDs for the key and for the for-each loop, but that is only a guess.

I know that the match statement for my key "gruppe" is not correct, because it says position() >= 4. The groups start at column6, so it should be position() >= 6, BUT because some users don't have mail adresses or phone numbers I have to start at position 4.
I know that because of the (sometimes) missing columns, positions is not viable in this case, but I don't know how to select the groups inside the key like I do in the for-each loop.

It would be nice if someone could help me, the desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
<Name>Children</Name>
<Name>DarlingFamily</Name>
<Name>Parents</Name>
<Name>Animals</Name>
<Name>Maid</Name>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So you do not need the other columns? Only a distinct list of *Group1* and *Group2* (cols 6 and 7)?

Comment: Yes, for the first part of the import process I only need to import all the groups. A disctinct list of Column6, Column7, Column8 and so forth. The rest of the import process (importing users, connecting them to the imported groups etc.) is already working, so I left that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all non-numeric characters from the columnX name and then check it is greater than or equal to 6 to select all columns with groups:

```
  <xsl:key name="group" match="Tabelle1/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Column') and translate(local-name(), translate(local-name(), '0123456789', ''), '') >= 6]" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Categories>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Tabelle1/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Column') and translate(local-name(), translate(local-name(), '0123456789', ''), '') >= 6][generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', .)[1])]">
            <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Categories>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEL

Comment: Thanks! That works. I had the idea to add numbers to the Column nametag but couldn't figure out how to do it. This is really a nice answer.